# Caching issue with WebClient/HttpClient

Tags: caching, windows-phone-8, httprequest, webclient, system.reactive

I'm developing a code to poll a Bitstamp exchange ticker every 30 seconds. This is a code I have:

```
public IObservable<string> Stream(Uri way, WebClient wc)
    {
        Func<IObserver<string>, Task> Fun = async Observer =>
        {
            var res = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(way);
            Observer.OnNext(value: res);
        };

        return Observable.Create<string>(Fun);
    }

public IObservable<string> GetDelay(int secs)
    {
        var exe = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secs);
        return Observable.Empty<string>("x").Delay(exe);
    }

Stream(new Uri("https://bitstamp.net/api/ticker"), new WebClient { }).Concat(GetDelay(30))
    .Repeat(5).Subscribe(res => Debug.WriteLine("got result: {0}", res));
```

The problem is that `WebClient` (and `HttpClient`, too) both return cached results after the first call, it can be seen by the same timestamp:

`got result: {"high": "690.00", "last": "645.10", "timestamp": "1387715532" ... }`
`got result: {"high": "690.00", "last": "645.10", "timestamp": "1387715532" ... }`
...

Even after turning the networks off they return the result normally so obviously they cache it somewhere. Adding something like "?cache=random" does not work because request parameters are not allowed for ticker on Bitstamp. Setting `Headers[HttpRequestHeader.CacheControl] = "no-cache"` for `WebRequest` does not work either.

How can I fix this weird caching behavior?

Comment: Are you sure this has anything to do with `WebClient`?  Have you tried just using a browser or Fiddler?  Sounds like a misconfigured proxy somewhere along the way.

Comment: @Brandon seems it has to do with `WebClient` or whatever mechanism below it because browser calls do not cache. Anyway, I've found a working solution.

Comment: What do you expect to gain by using async-await? Why don't just use [Observable.FromEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.fromevent.aspx) or [Observable.FromEventPattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.fromeventpattern.aspx)?

Comment: @PauloMorgado well it's just my design decision. Why is it worse than ’FromEvent’?

Comment: Are you aware that every async method is a state machine? A state machine that needs to be instantiated and run every time you call "the method"?

Comment: @PauloMorgado no, I was not aware of that. I also have a rather narrow understanding of what exactly a state machine is. Does it have a noticable performance impact over `Observable.FromEvent`?

Comment: The `WebClient` was not developed from the ground up for `async-await`. The TaskAsync methods are just wrapper around the -Async methods. So I expect `Observable.FromEvent`to be more performant. If you choose to go with `HttpClient`, then I recommend [Observable.FromAsyncPattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.fromasyncpattern.aspx) because `Task` implements `IAsyncResult`.

Comment: @PauloMorgado ok, I'll change the code and utilize 'FromEvent' instead of what I have now. Thanks for a valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved by setting `wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.IfModifiedSince] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();` before each subsequent call.

Comment: you should probably set it to the `Last-Modified` value from the previous response if the server returns it.

Comment: Had the same problem and I could solve it with setting the webClientHeader.

Answer (score 5):

For Windows Phone Setting with Language=Chinese and "date+time" is not "24-hour clock" ,
the code `wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.IfModifiedSince] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString()` causes exception throwing since `DateTime.ToString()` generates Chinese characters "下午" in the header.

The safer solution is to output the date time format as [RFC1123 pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.IfModifiedSince] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R");
```

This will ensure the date time is in format of "Sat, 05 Jul 2014 13:38:28 GMT", and there will no any Chinese characters within the HTTP headers.

Comment: I just love to write software that blows up unexpectedly.